# Purdue Compiler Construction Tool Set (PCCTS) : website, tutorial, book?

Tags: metaprogramming, compiler-construction

I am a college student and have been asked to familiarize myself with PCCTS, Purdu Compiler Construction Tool Set. I have been given a link to http://www.polhode.com/pccts.html

I have to code some basic program in PCCTS and later on use the knowledge in compiler optimization.

As such there are a few results available on google for this purpose but it would take some time to go through all of them to find out anything useful. If anyone knows of more tutorials, books, website or some basic guidance on this topic, it would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe going through those links was one of the things your teachers wanted you to do?

Comment: Agree completely. Of late there has been a spike in the 'Shortcut to success' type of questions. Wonder how one addresses them.